# Best Practice/Pattern for iphone login session

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services

I need a recommendation on how to implement a login session for iphone + web service.

Do I generate a token and pass that token every time I make a request to the web service?

1. Login
2. Get token
3. Send token to server with every request.

   - Token will expire in x-minutes

Would this be a common implementation?

please advise

Comment: I did the first step but I don't know how to do the next two steps which are: 2.Get token and 3.Send token to server with every request, the link of the answer for this question is not working, I would appreciate if you help me.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the basic idea. There are of course other options. The RestKit discussion board example does it pretty well:

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/tree/master/Examples/RKDiscussionBoardExample/DiscussionBoard